How to prevent clicking outside a popover HTML element?
I'm using a popover element to display a loading spinner while performing an asynchronous action like so


function doAsyncStuff() {
  const loadingScreenHtmlElement = document.getElementById("loading-screen");

  loadingScreenHtmlElement.showPopover();

  setTimeout(() => {
    loadingScreenHtmlElement.hidePopover();
  }, 3000);
}
#loading-screen::backdrop {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
<div popover id="loading-screen">
  <div>Loading spinner goes here</div>
</div>

<button onclick="doAsyncStuff()">Do it</button>



As you can see there are 2 problems

One can close the shown popover by clicking outside
One can access elements "behind" the popover, e.g. clicking the button again

Based on How to disable clicking inside div adding pointer-events:none to #loading-screen did not help. How do I fix this?

Perhaps the manual attribute for the popover would help? Per the mdn documentation:  ... manual popovers must always be explicitly hidden, but allow for use cases such as nested popovers in menus.

I'm not sure this would be the best approach, but you may try listening for the click event over the whole document and just check for a condition before doing preventDefault()... by condition I mean a flag stating if the popover is shown or not. Otherwise you'd need an overlay on top of everything having pointer-events: none or trying to toggle a class doing that over body(?)

by the away I confirm the suggestion given by @mykaf ... Using manual popover state - The popover cannot be "light dismissed", although declarative show/hide/toggle buttons (as seen earlier) will still work.

Instead of backdrop, perhaps a pseudo-element underlay - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/eYqrKLm


One can close the shown popover by clicking outside

This is default behaviour for popover=auto (shortcut: popover).

auto state, and "light dismiss"
When a popover element is set with popover or popover="auto" as shown above, it is said to have auto state. The two important behaviors to note about auto state are:
The popover can be "light dismissed" — this means that you can hide the popover by clicking outside it.

So a popover=manual will prevent closing the popover when clicking outside.


One can access elements "behind" the popover, e.g. clicking the button again

Clicking under the popover can't be disabled with pointer-events. You'll need to extend some other element on the page so that you can use that as a blocker.
I've added an <div id='loading-blocker'></div> which is hidden by default but shown using the following css:
:popover-open + #loading-blocker {
  display: block;
}

Another way is to check the target of the click event and stop processing (stopPropagation()) if it's on the backdrop. But the above CSS solution seems like a more fitting/scaleable solution



function doAsyncStuff() {
  const loadingScreenHtmlElement = document.getElementById("loading-screen");

  loadingScreenHtmlElement.showPopover();

  setTimeout(() => {
    loadingScreenHtmlElement.hidePopover();
  }, 5000);
}
#loading-screen::backdrop {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

:popover-open + #loading-blocker {
  display: block;
}

#loading-blocker {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: transparent;
    pointer-events: all;
}
<div popover='manual' id="loading-screen">
  <div>Loading spinner goes here</div>
  
</div>
<div id='loading-blocker'></div>

<button onclick="doAsyncStuff()">Do it</button>




thanks for the popover=manual solution. But how do I extend some other element as a blocker?

wrap all the code with the exception of the constant inside an if statement such as: if (!loadingScreenHtmlElement.checkVisibility()) { ... }. Then the code will only be executed if the popover is not visible.

There is an :popover-open pseudo element that we can use to toggle some other overlay that will capture the click events.
